# Привязка класса к HTML элементу

Tags: javascript, html

Итак, есть у меня в HTML элемент `DIV` (Данных элементов может быть много):

```
  <div class="comp-card-slot card-slot">
      <div class="card" data-value="0 0 0 0">MILITIA</div></div>
```

Есть класс Cards, в котором есть функция, которая должна связывать содержимое класса с элементом `DIV` класс `Card`:

```
class Cards {
  constructor(suits, attak, attaktipe, accuracy, health, defence, speed, dexterity) {
    this.suits = suits;
    this.attak = attak;
    this.attaktipe = attaktipe;
    this.accuracy = accuracy;
    this.health = health;
    this.defence = defence;
    this.speed = speed;
    this.dexterity = dexterity;
  };
  getHTML() {
    const CardDIV = document.createElement('div');
    cardDIV.innerText = this.suits;
    cardDIV.classList.add("card");
    cardDIV.dataset.value = `${this.attak} ${this.health} ${this.defence} ${this.speed}`;
    return CardDIV;
  };
};
```

Есть код, который, по идее, должен выполнять связывание HTML и JS-кода:

```
const PC_Card_Slot = document.querySelector('.comp-card-slot');
PC_Card_Slot.appendChild(DECK_PC.Cards[0].getHTML());
```

Но при попытке выполнить этот код, консоль начинает ругаться вот так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Подозреваю, что он не распознает мой массив DECK_PC. Но данная переменная обьявлена у меня в коде и заполнена элементами класса Cards. Что я делаю не так?

Переменная DECK_PC отображается в консоли вот так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

После смещения кода под дивы в консоли перестали нравиться мои ключи:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Можете выложить код на одну из js песочниц? у вас отсутствует элемент с классом .comp-card-slot

Comment: Да нет, такой элемент у меня есть `<div class="comp-card-slot card-slot">` 

Про песочницы ничего не знаю, так что если подскажете о чем идет речь и как туда что-либо добавлять, то могу попробовать выложить там свой код.

Comment: @ у вас в диве класс кард, а в скрипте кардс так и должно быть?

Comment: Да, див имеет класс `card` а элементы, которые должны считываться из массива и отображаться в диве являются `Cards`.

Comment: Добавил скрин массива в консоли.

Comment: @drakoblack покажите что вы делаете на строке 89, на которой ошибка. А песочницы: https://jsfiddle.net/ https://codepen.io/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. 

Ошибка не имеет никакого отношения к массиву `DECK_PC`, а говорит о том, что вызов `document.querySelector(...)` вернул `null`.

Ваш код

```
const PC_Card_Slot = document.querySelector('.comp-card-slot');
PC_Card_Slot.appendChild(DECK_PC.Cards[0].getHTML());
```

выполняется до того, как на странице появится элемент c `class="comp-card-slot ..."`.

Пeренесите код в конец страницы - перед `</body>`.

---

2. 

Если `DECK_PC` - массив, то использовать его надо так:

```
PC_Card_Slot.appendChild(DECK_PC[0].getHTML());
```

---

3. 

JavaScript - язык, чувствительный к регистру. В методе `getHTML` Вы объявили переменную `CardDIV`, а на следующей строчке используете `cardDIV`.

```
  getHTML() {
    const CardDIV = document.createElement('div');
    cardDIV.innerText = this.suits;
    cardDIV.classList.add("card");
    cardDIV.dataset.value = `${this.attak} ${this.health} ${this.defence} ${this.speed}`;
    return CardDIV;
  };
```

---

Поясню. Слово "дурачок" относится не к уровню знания языка JavaScript, а к форме задания вопросов. Представьте, что к Вам обращается коллега и говорит: "У меня консоль ругается. Как исправить?" "дурачок" - самый вежливый из эпитетов, которые он заслуживает.

Comment: Сделал, как Вы посоветовали и переместил код под элементы див. В резальтате консоль начала ругаться на  `[0]` Скрин прикрепил к первому посту.

Comment: @drakoblack Я не знаю, что означает "консоль начала ругаться", и что такое `DECK_PC`.

Comment: DECK_PC - это массив с элементами класс Cards. "Ругаться" = выдавать ошибки.

Comment: @drakoblack Вы  - дурачок? Какие ошибки? Уберите `Cards`: `DECK_PC[0].getHTML()`.

Comment: обзываться вовсе не обязательно. Я только начал изучать js и многое для меня не понятно. Собственно говоря, поэтому здесь и обращаюсь за помощью, чтобы мне прояснили что да как. Если я все знал и умел, то смысл бы мне здесь подобные вопросы задавать было бы?

Comment: Удаление `Cards` из `DECK_PC[0].getHTML()` приводит к ошибке `cardDIV is not defined`/

Comment: @drakoblack JavaScript - язык, чувствительный к регистру. В методе `getHTML` Вы объявили переменную `CardDIV`, а на следующей строчке используете `cardDIV`.

Comment: спасибо, все вроде начало работать.